# strange settings/options page of Chrome extension

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, html-select

I am reading a Chrome extension codes. In one of its html files (used for setting), the source code shows that there is a `select` element like this

```
<select id="hostselect"></select>
```

Note that there is no `option` element as the child of the `select` element. However, if I open the setting page of the extension in Chrome, there is a drop-down list corresponding to that `select` element, and moreover, if I use the Chrome developer tool to inspect this setting page, it shows that the `select` element has `option` children:

```
<select id="hostselect">
  <option value="host1">host1</option>
  <option value="hots2">host2</option>
</select>
```

I don't understand why there is no `option` child if I view the source code of the setting page in text editor, while the `option` children appear when I view the page's DOM using Chrome developer tool. What could be the most possible reason for this? Could some content scripts in the extension change the DOM of the setting page? Also, what's the benefit to write codes like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this for an extension at work. I am using Javascript to load extra options in to the select. I do this because the number of options is dynamic. I don't have source available now but I can post an example later if you would like

**Update**

Here is an example of some javascript that might populate your `select` element. I am using jQuery to append the options and to iterate over my list of hosts with jQuery's `each`. I have two static options "Default" and "None" the the dynamic list which was generated with `getHosts()`

```
var hosts = getHosts();
if(hosts) {
    var selectElement = $("#hostSelect");
    selectElement.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", "0").text("-- Default Host --"));
    selectElement.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", "-1").text("-- No Host Selected --"));
    $.each(hosts, function(key, host) {
        selectElement.append($("<option></option>").attr( "value", host.getHostID() ).text( host.getName() ));
    })
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example of one way to do something like this. If this helps you please upvote and accept :) Thanks